# I want to output specific observations based on conditional statements in SAS

Tags: logic, sas

Below is my code.  I want author to = known if it is one of the papers listed below and I want author to equal a character value equal to the corresponding paper number if it is not one of the papers listed below.  Once that is completed, I want to output the observations to two different data sets.  I want to output to knownauthor if the author is known and output to unknownauthor if the author is unknown.  I'm completeld stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
data knownauthor unknownauthor;
    set t_wordlist_summary;
        if paper=1-17 or paper=21-48 or paper=59-61 or paper=64-85 then author="known";
        else author=input(paper, 2.);
        if author="known" then output knownauthor;
        else output unknownauthor;
```

Comment: This looks just fine.  What happens when you run it?

Comment: It dumps all of my observations into the "unknownauthor" dataset.  And it also does not assign a value "known" to the specified papers.  And in the "unknownauthor" data set, the value of author shows up as a missing value.

Comment: This is what SAS writes to the log specifically:

Comment: NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places given by:
      (Line):(Column).
      130:13   130:19
NOTE: There were 85 observations read from the data set WORK.T_WORDLIST_SUMMARY.
NOTE: The data set WORK.KNOWNAUTHOR has 0 observations and 32 variables.
NOTE: The data set WORK.UNKNOWNAUTHOR has 85 observations and 32 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Here i have created new dataline. and coded according to your details.

data new;
input paper ;
cards;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
;

data known unknown;
  set new;
  if 1 le paper le 3 or 5 le paper le 9  then  do;
     author = "Know";
  output known;
  end;

else  do;
    author=compress(put(paper,best.));
  output unknown;
  end;
run;

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional expression

```
if paper=1-17 or paper=21-48 or paper=59-61 or paper=64-85
```

looks wrong. It's now actually equivalent to the condition `if paper=-16 or paper=-27 or paper=-2 or paper=-21` which obviously not what you meant, right?. You need to rewrite it as

```
1<=paper<=17 or 21<=paper<=48 or 59<=paper<=61 or 64<=paper<=85
```

And another issue with `author=input(paper, 2.)`. If you want to convert numeric paper values into characters, then you have to use put() function instead.